# Catch Script Execution Time in PHP

Tags: php, time, execution

Following script is to create 1 lack html buttons.

```
<?php 
for($i=1; $i<=100000;$i++)
{
    echo "<button>".$i."</button>";
}
?>
```

I need to catch/record the time. At the end, the result should shows: 
**Script take "x" minutes, "x" seconds and "x" milliseconds**. Actually I am cloning a virtual machine that takes about 4 to 5 minutes depending upon the size of the disk. So that's why I need customized output.

Comment: Look at the examples at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight off [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php):

```
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$time_start = microtime_float();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100000; $i++)
{
    echo "<button>".$i."</button>";
}

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Time taken = $time seconds\n";
```

I'd be extremely concerned about your hardware spec if your PHP script took minutes to execute ;)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am working on my thesis project so I haven't such a high performance hardware. Well one more thing; I got the result that is: 0.23803281784058 Seconds according to your program. So is there is any way to customized it? How I can change it to minutes:seconds:milliseconds?

Answer (score -1):

Deduct end from start time:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
//du stuff there like this
sleep(1);
//and print time in sec
echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

For your case:

```
$start = microtime(true);

for($i=1; $i<=100000;$i++){
    echo "<button>".$i."</button>";
}

$sec = (microtime(true) - $start);
$mil = explode('.', (string)$sec);
$mil = number_format($mil[1], 3);
$min = $sec / 60;

echo "Script take '$min' minutes, '$sec' seconds and '$mil' miliseconds";
```